# Rails 5 delayed job, how to check the job status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, delayed-job

I am using a delayed job on a Rails 5 project with the 'delayed_job_active_record' gem.

I can't figure out how to check on the status of the job.

I managed to get delayed job to run.  The jobs are failing due to an issue with processing uploaded files (that's another issue).

In my controller:

```
def create
  @upload = Upload.create(status: "in progress")
  @upload.delay.create_ln(lecture_note_params, current_user, @upload.id)
  render json: {"status": @upload.status, "id": @upload.id}, status: 200
end
```

Here's my model code for the upload model:

```
class Upload < ApplicationRecord
    def create_ln(lecture_note_params, current_user, upload_id)
         @lecture_note = LectureNote.new(lecture_note_params.merge(user: current_user))
         @lecture_note.upload_id = upload_id
        if @lecture_note.save
          #nothing
        else
          logger.info @lecture_note.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
          @upload.update(error: @lecture_note.errors.full_messages.to_sentence, status: "error")      
        end
    end

end
```

The lecture notes don't save.  They fail for the reason mentioned above.  I need the upload model to update with the error status.  How can I do that?

I can see the delayed job in the console :

```
irb(main):002:0> ap Delayed::Job.last
D, [2019-12-12T06:12:08.014249 #4] DEBUG -- :   Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job Load (6.3ms)  SELECT  `delayed_jobs`.* FROM `delayed_jobs` ORDER BY `delayed_jobs`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
#<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job:0x0000561edb710f70> {
            :id => 16,
      :priority => 0,
      :attempts => 1,
       :handler => "### ALL KINDS OF STUFF - REDACTED ###",
        :run_at => Thu, 12 Dec 2019 06:10:32 UTC +00:00,
     :locked_at => nil,
     :failed_at => Thu, 12 Dec 2019 06:11:17 UTC +00:00,
     :locked_by => nil,
         :queue => nil,
    :created_at => Thu, 12 Dec 2019 06:10:32 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Thu, 12 Dec 2019 06:11:17 UTC +00:00
}
```

After the job fails, the "failed_at" field is updated.  How can I access that and update my upload model?

Here is the log file while a file is uploading:

```
D, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.846638 #4] DEBUG -- :   Upload Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  `uploads`.* FROM `uploads` WHERE `uploads`.`id` = 31 LIMIT 1
D, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.852741 #4] DEBUG -- :   User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
[Worker(host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4)] Job Upload#create_ln (id=16) RUNNING
I, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.853180 #4]  INFO -- : 2019-12-12T06:11:17+0000: [Worker(host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4)] Job Upload#create_ln (id=16) RUNNING
D, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.855002 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.2ms)  BEGIN
I, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.855200 #4]  INFO -- : pdf to html running..............
I, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.855268 #4]  INFO -- : step 0 ..............
I, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.855326 #4]  INFO -- : step 1 ..............
I, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.855388 #4]  INFO -- : step 2 ..............
D, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.856673 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.1ms)  ROLLBACK
[Worker(host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4)] Job Upload#create_ln (id=16) FAILED (0 prior attempts) with IOError: uninitialized stream
E, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.857261 #4] ERROR -- : 2019-12-12T06:11:17+0000: [Worker(host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4)] Job Upload#create_ln (id=16) FAILED (0 prior attempts) with IOError: uninitialized stream
[Worker(host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4)] Job Upload#create_ln (id=16) FAILED permanently because of 1 consecutive failures
E, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.857416 #4] ERROR -- : 2019-12-12T06:11:17+0000: [Worker(host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4)] Job Upload#create_ln (id=16) FAILED permanently because of 1 consecutive failures
D, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.858576 #4] DEBUG -- :    (0.9ms)  BEGIN
D, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.861961 #4] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.6ms)  UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET `last_error` = 'uninitialized stream\n/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tempfile.rb:221:in `path\'\n/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tempfile.rb:221:in `path\'\n/app/app/models/lecture_note.rb:60:in `pdf_to_html\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:382:in `block in make_lambda\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:150:in `block (2 levels) in halting_and_conditional\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:770:in `block (2 levels) in deprecated_false_terminator\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:769:in `catch\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:769:in `block in deprecated_false_terminator\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `block in call\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `each\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:454:in `call\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_validation_callbacks\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.7.1/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `run_validations!\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activemodel-5.0.7.1/lib/active_model/validations.rb:338:in `valid?\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:65:in `valid?\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:82:in `perform_validations\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:44:in `save\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block (2 levels) in save\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block in save\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:334:in `rollback_active_record_state!\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:318:in `save\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.7.1/lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:41:in `save\'\n/app/app/models/upload.rb:7:in `create_ln\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/performable_method.rb:26:in `perform\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:81:in `block in invoke_job\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:78:in `invoke_job\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/worker.rb:230:in `block (2 levels) in run\'\n/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/timeout.rb:93:in `block in timeout\'\n/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/worker.rb:230:in `block in run\'\n/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/worker.rb:229:in `run\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/worker.rb:312:in `block in reserve_and_run_one_job\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/worker.rb:312:in `reserve_and_run_one_job\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/worker.rb:213:in `block in work_off\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/worker.rb:212:in `times\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/worker.rb:212:in `work_off\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/worker.rb:175:in `block (4 levels) in start\'\n/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/worker.rb:174:in `block (3 levels) in start\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/worker.rb:173:in `block (2 levels) in start\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/worker.rb:172:in `loop\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/worker.rb:172:in `block in start\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/plugins/clear_locks.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ClearLocks>\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block (2 levels) in add\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:61:in `block in initialize\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:79:in `block in add\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:66:in `execute\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/lifecycle.rb:40:in `run_callbacks\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/worker.rb:171:in `start\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/delayed_job-4.1.8/lib/delayed/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `block in execute\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `each\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:273:in `execute\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:214:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain\'\n/app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/monitor.rb:230:in `mon_synchronize\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `invoke_with_call_chain\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in `invoke\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `invoke_task\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in top_level\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `each\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `block in top_level\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:125:in `run_with_threads\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `top_level\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:83:in `block in run\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rake:23:in `load\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:463:in `exec\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors\'\n/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>\'\n/app/bin/bundle:3:in `load\'\n/app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>\'', `attempts` = 1, `failed_at` = '2019-12-12 06:11:17', `updated_at` = '2019-12-12 06:11:17' WHERE `delayed_jobs`.`id` = 16
D, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.867680 #4] DEBUG -- :    (5.1ms)  COMMIT
D, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.870699 #4] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.8ms)  UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET `delayed_jobs`.`locked_at` = '2019-12-12 06:11:17', `delayed_jobs`.`locked_by` = 'host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4' WHERE ((run_at <= '2019-12-12 06:11:17.867786' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2019-12-12 02:11:17.867819') OR locked_by = 'host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1
[Worker(host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4)] 8 jobs processed at 13.8130 j/s, 8 failed
I, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.870885 #4]  INFO -- : 2019-12-12T06:11:17+0000: [Worker(host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4)] 8 jobs processed at 13.8130 j/s, 8 failed
D, [2019-12-12T06:11:17.873258 #4] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.2ms)  UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET `delayed_jobs`.`locked_at` = '2019-12-12 06:11:17', `delayed_jobs`.`locked_by` = 'host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4' WHERE ((run_at <= '2019-12-12 06:11:17.870973' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2019-12-12 02:11:17.871010') OR locked_by = 'host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1
D, [2019-12-12T06:11:22.878755 #4] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.5ms)  UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET `delayed_jobs`.`locked_at` = '2019-12-12 06:11:22', `delayed_jobs`.`locked_by` = 'host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4' WHERE ((run_at <= '2019-12-12 06:11:22.876103' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2019-12-12 02:11:22.876164') OR locked_by = 'host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1
D, [2019-12-12T06:11:27.882776 #4] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.6ms)  UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET `delayed_jobs`.`locked_at` = '2019-12-12 06:11:27', `delayed_jobs`.`locked_by` = 'host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4' WHERE ((run_at <= '2019-12-12 06:11:27.880101' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2019-12-12 02:11:27.880160') OR locked_by = 'host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1
D, [2019-12-12T06:11:32.890712 #4] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.6ms)  UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET `delayed_jobs`.`locked_at` = '2019-12-12 06:11:32', `delayed_jobs`.`locked_by` = 'host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4' WHERE ((run_at <= '2019-12-12 06:11:32.887163' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2019-12-12 02:11:32.887243') OR locked_by = 'host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1
D, [2019-12-12T06:11:37.894751 #4] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.5ms)  UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET `delayed_jobs`.`locked_at` = '2019-12-12 06:11:37', `delayed_jobs`.`locked_by` = 'host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4' WHERE ((run_at <= '2019-12-12 06:11:37.892094' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at < '2019-12-12 02:11:37.892153') OR locked_by = 'host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4') AND failed_at IS NULL) ORDER BY priority ASC, run_at ASC LIMIT 1
^C[Worker(host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4)] Exiting...
I, [2019-12-12T06:11:39.976787 #4]  INFO -- : 2019-12-12T06:11:39+0000: [Worker(host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4)] Exiting...
D, [2019-12-12T06:11:42.902214 #4] DEBUG -- :   SQL (5.4ms)  UPDATE `delayed_jobs` SET `delayed_jobs`.`locked_by` = NULL, `delayed_jobs`.`locked_at` = NULL WHERE `delayed_jobs`.`locked_by` = 'host:575e618d-28f3-49a1-8545-88afa11b60d1 pid:4'
```

Comment: Is your create method being called via js?

Comment: Rails is being used as an API.  The controller is triggered by JS but the method is run in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found the solution.  Tun's answer pointed me in the general direction (very general direction) but led me to it.

delayed_job has callbacks but I didn't know where to put them, or how to use them.  They simply go in the model where the job method takes place.  That wasn't obvious in the available documentation (to me anyway).

I was looking at this the wrong way.  I already have the upload class to manage the creation of the lecture notes.  So using the callbacks I can have the job update the class with the status.  That's what we needed in the end.

The `def failure(job)` method did the trick!

I don't 100% understand how these callbacks actually work behind the scenes but they do work.

```
class Upload < ApplicationRecord


    def create_ln(lecture_note_params, current_user, upload_id)
         @lecture_note = LectureNote.new(lecture_note_params.merge(user: current_user))
         @lecture_note.upload_id = upload_id
        # if @lecture_note.save
        #   #nothing
        # else
        #   logger.info @lecture_note.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
        #   @upload.update(error: @lecture_note.errors.full_messages.to_sentence, status: "error")      
        # end
        begin
          @lecture_note.save
        rescue Exception => e
          puts @lecture_note.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
          self.update(error: @lecture_note.errors.full_messages.to_sentence, status: "error")      
        end
    end

     def success(job)
      puts "Job complete ------->"
    end

    def error(job, exception)
      puts "Job failed ERROR ------->"
      puts @lecture_note.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      self.update(error: @lecture_note.errors.full_messages.to_sentence, status: "error") 
    end

    # def after(job)
    #   # Do something useful here
    # end

    def failure(job)
     puts "Job failed FAILURE ------->"
      puts @lecture_note.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
      self.update(error: @lecture_note.errors.full_messages.to_sentence, status: "error") 
    end
end
```

Comment: [The Hook (available only to job)](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#hooks) is already in place and you use it. [Proposed Global Hooks](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Global-Hooks-Proposal) are supposed to be better but not released yet.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, we should not check the job. The job should report back. (Observer pattern - I think)

I usually do one or combination of the followings

- ActionCable to inform progress of the job (exception in your case)
- Catch Exception in the job and update Upload with status
- Use third party gem (such as [activity_notification](https://rubygems.org/gems/activity_notification/versions/2.0.0) for notification.

[DelayedJob proposed Global Hooks](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Global-Hooks-Proposal) but I think it is not implemented yet.

Comment: Thanks Tun, "Catch Exception in the job and update Upload with status" makes sense.  Where would I add that code?  In the method that is being sent to delayed_job?

That would be create_ln in my case.  What would the code look like?